# I want to add React Router <Link> in js dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to add  in selected DOM's innerHTMl but the code isn't working as I want, the being  tag but it should be an a tag in dev tool and also clickable, but it's not
what are the problems and solutions?

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './css/App.css';

function Home() {
    
  function compiOver (){
    document.getElementById('compi').innerHTML="<Link to='/about'>About</Link>"
  };
  function compiOut (){
    document.getElementById('compi').innerHTML="Hello."
  };
  

  return (
    <div className='home'>
      <h1 className='home__child' id='home__comp'>
          <span className='home-comps' id='compi' onMouseOver={compiOver} onMouseOut={compiOut}>Hello.</span><br></br>
      </h1>
      <Link to='/contact'>hdajga</Link>//it's being a hyperlink 
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: This will never work, instead, set a true/false flag on hover and then show what you want based on that `showLink ? <Link to='/about'>About</Link> : 'Hello'` - plus, you're trying to overwrite the html that's actually got the `onMouseOut` method in it

Comment: I'm not getting you, actually. Can you be more descriptive?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't manipulate the DOM as you did, in this case just declare a variable with JSX content and render it :

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './css/App.css';
function Home() {
    const [dynamicContent,setDynamicContent]=useState('Hello')
 
   function compiOver (){
   setDynamicContent(<Link to='/about'>About</Link>)
  };
  function compiOut (){
    setDynamicContent("Hello.")
  };
  

  return (
    <div className='home'>
      <h1 className='home__child' id='home__comp'>
          <span className='home-comps' id='compi' onMouseOver={compiOver} onMouseOut={compiOut}>
         {dynamicContent}
        </span><br></br>
      </h1>
      <Link to='/contact'>hdajga</Link>//it's being a hyperlink 
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: not working, actually. can I try in a different way?

Comment: `src\Home.js
  Line 7:44:  'useState' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.` getting this error message.

Comment: You should import it `import React,{useState} from "react";`